# How does it derived from LHS term

Tags: trigonometry

$$\sin\left(\frac{720n\pi}{600}\right) = -\sin\left(\frac{4n\pi}{5}\right).$$

It is a part of derivation I found in an example but this step is not clear to me if I tried to just divide and use reminder but it is not same and $\sin(n\pi) = 0$ so it is not near to above step.

Please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. We have that
$$\sin(720/600\cdot n\cdot\pi)=\sin((2-4/5)\cdot\pi\cdot n). $$
Then recall that $\sin(x+2n\pi)=\sin(x)$ and $\sin(-x)=-\sin(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sin{(720/600 n \pi)}$$$$=\sin{(6/5 n \pi)}$$$$=\sin{((2-4/5) n \pi)}$$
$$=\sin{(2 n \pi-4/5n\pi)}$$$$=\sin{(-4/5 n \pi)}$$$$=-\sin{(4/5 n \pi)}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{720}{600} = \frac{72}{60}=\frac{12}{10}=\frac{6}{5} = 2 - \frac{4}{5}.$$

Now you write $$\sin\left(\frac{\pi n \cdot 720}{600}\right) =\sin\left( 2\pi n -\frac{\pi n \cdot 4}{5}\right) =  \sin\left(-\frac{\pi n \cdot 4}{5}\right) =-\sin\left(\frac{\pi n \cdot 4}{5}\right)$$